# D3JS Force Layout new nodes disconnects existing nodes

Tags: javascript, d3.js, force-layout

When I add new nodes to D3's Force Layout, the new nodes ignore the previous nodes when positioning itself and the previous nodes becomes un-draggable. I feel I've followed the logic of:

1. Add elements to arrays nodes and links
2. Updated force.nodes(nodes) and force.links(links)
3. Ran through .data().enter() with new data
4. Called force.start()

But still results in previous nodes disconnects. The new nodes are draggable and appears to take into consideration the LAST SET of added nodes position and avoids collision, all other previous nodes are clickable still, but their positioning are ignored and not updated.

Here is a the code in PLNKR: http://plnkr.co/edit/5fXZf63s73cTO37zLjNQ?p=preview

```
var width = 1000;
var height = 600;
var node_w = 30;
var node_h = 30;
var text_dx = -20;
var text_dy = 20;
var new_id = 9;
var nodes = [],
    links = [],
    links_line,
    node_circles;   

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width",width)
    .attr("height",height);     

var nodes = [
                { "name": "Nucleus" , "size" : 25, "id" : 0 , "color":"#ac0000"},
                { "name": "one"     , "size" : 5 , "id": 1  , "color": "#ac0"},
                { "name": "two"     , "size" : 15 , "id": 2 , "color": "#ac0"},
                { "name": "three"   , "size" : 25 , "id": 3 , "color": "#ac0"},
                { "name": "four"    , "size" : 9 , "id": 4  , "color": "#ac0"},
                { "name": "five"    , "size" : 12 , "id": 5 , "color": "#ac0"},
                { "name": "six"     , "size" : 15 , "id": 6 , "color": "#ac0"},
                { "name": "seven"   , "size" : 41 , "id": 7 , "color": "#ac0"},
                { "name": "eight"   , "size" : 5 , "id": 8  , "color": "#ac0"}
            ];
var links = [
                { "source": 0 , "target": 1 , "link_info":"r01" },
                { "source": 1 , "target": 2 , "link_info":"r31" },
                { "source": 1 , "target": 3 , "link_info":"r02" },
                { "source": 1 , "target": 4 , "link_info":"r04" },
                { "source": 0 , "target": 5 , "link_info":"r05" },
                { "source": 0 , "target": 6 , "link_info":"r06" },
                { "source": 0 , "target": 7 , "link_info":"r87" },
                { "source": 0 , "target": 8 , "link_info":"r87" }
            ];

var force = d3.layout.force()
      .nodes(nodes)
      .links(links)
      .size([width, height])
      .linkDistance(150)
      .charge(-1400);

var drag = force.drag();


init();

function init() {

    force.start();  

    links_line = svg.selectAll("line")
      .data(links)
      .enter()
      .append("line")
      .style("stroke", "#ac0")
      .style("stroke-width", 1);

    node_circles = svg.selectAll("circle")
      .data(nodes)
      .enter()
      .append("circle")
      .style("fill", function(d) {return d.color;})
      .on("dblclick", function(d, i) {
        addNodes(i);                
      })
      .call(drag);

    draw();
}


function addNodes(i) {
    for (c=0; c < Math.floor(Math.random() * 20) + 4; c++) {
        nodes.push({"name": "new " + new_id,"size": (Math.floor(Math.random() * 20) + 10),"id": new_id,"color": "#333"})
        links.push({"source": i,"target": new_id,"link_info": "r"+i+new_id});
        new_id++;
    }

    // Update force.nodes
    force.nodes(nodes);

    // Update force.links
    force.links(links);

    // exec init()
    init();         
}


function draw() {

    var ticksPerRender = 1;

    requestAnimationFrame(function render() {
        force.tick();
        //Update nodes
        node_circles.attr("cx", function(d) {return d.x - d.size / 6;});
        node_circles.attr("cy", function(d) {return d.y - d.size / 6;});
        node_circles.attr("r", function(d) {return d.size});

        //Update Location line
        links_line.attr("x1", function(d) {return d.source.x;});
        links_line.attr("y1", function(d) {return d.source.y;});
        links_line.attr("x2", function(d) {return d.target.x;});
        links_line.attr("y2", function(d) {return d.target.y;});

        requestAnimationFrame(render)

    });

} // draw();
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Updating a d3 visualization follows an enter, update, and exit workflow (start your reading [here](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/join/) and [here](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/circles/)).

Try this instead:

```
function init() {

    force.start();  

    links_line = svg.selectAll("line")
      .data(links);

    links_line
      .enter()
      .append("line")
      .style("stroke", "#ac0")
      .style("stroke-width", 1);

    links_line.exit().remove();

    node_circles = svg.selectAll("circle")
        .data(nodes);

    node_circles
        .enter()
        .append("circle")
        .style("fill", function(d) {return d.color;})
        .on("dblclick", function(d, i) {
            addNodes(i);                
        })
        .call(drag);

        draw();
}
```

Updated [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/QXPEs4NOq2uKpoG8WMOi?p=preview).